# What's the best way to add the same ajax function to a list of comments?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Source code is like this:

```
<div>
    <h4>comment content</h4>
    <a id="delcmt_{{ comment.id }}">delete this comment</a>
</div>
......
<div>
    <h4>comment content</h4>
    <a id="delcmt_{{ comment.id }}">delete this comment</a>
</div>
```

I what to add ajax function to each of the "delete this comment" link:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#delcmt_id').bind('click', function() {
      $.get($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/del_comment', {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").value(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

What I can come out is using a loop to copy the upper ajax function for each comment, that must be very ugly. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a class and select it with jquery add an event handler. You have to use the 'on' event because the elements you wish attach behavior to might be dynamic and load after document ready.

```
   @*Render all this with razor, or angular or knockout*@
    <div>
        <h4>comment content</h4>
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" id="1" data-rowid="1" class="delete-me-class">delete this comment</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>comment content</h4>
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" id="2" data-rowid="2" class="delete-me-class">delete this comment</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.delete-me-class', function () {//http://api.jquery.com/on/  on is the latest 'live' binding for elements that may not exists when DOM is ready.
                var rowId = $(this).data('rowid');
                //TODO Use rowId for your delete ajax, or your element Id if you wish.
                alert('You clicked on the delete link with the row ID of ' + rowId);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ga9H/)